# Copying a git repo via "sneakernet"

Tags: git

I created a bare git repo on my VPS (virtual private server). I then did a `git clone` to one of my local machines, call it **local1**, added a large number of files, committed them, and did `git push`. So I've transferred these files (totalling a few GB) through the internet once.

Now I want to have the same repo on some other local machines, but *I want to avoid transferring all of those files back through internet again*. Instead of using `git clone`, can I just copy the repo from **local1** onto a USB drive, and then copy that to the other machines **local2**, **local3**, etc? Or is there a better way to do this?

**EDIT:** All the machines in question are connected to the internet. Once the repos are set up, I plan to `git push` and `git pull` normally, because I will only modify a few files at a time. It's just the initial transfer of the full set of files that I'm concerned about.

Comment: Just copy the repo files, the .git directory will hold all the revisions and history. You can tar gzip then, and put them on a drive or use scp if sshd is running on one of the machines, you could use rsync and skip the tar also.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes you can just copy the whole directory (make sure to copy the hidden `.git` directory inside which contains all the "git metadata").

Alternatively you can clone from one local machine to another:

```
git clone local1-ip:/path/to/repository
```

and in the end you can just change the url of **origin** to point to your VPS:

```
git remote set-url origin VPS:url.git
```

Answer (score 1):

The approach of copying the `.git` subdirectory works fine for creating the clone, however you achieve it (file browser, `tar`, `cp`, `scp`, whatever). However, that leaves one problem: Transmitting updates.

There are two ways to transmit new commits efficiently:

- If both machines are connected to the internet, you may just push/pull from both machines to synchronize.
- If the second machine is air-gaped, you can still ingest new commits efficiently by using `git bundle`:

  `git bundle create <path/to/new/file/on/stick.bundle> <old-master>..master` will pack all the commits between `<old-master>` and `master` into a bundle file, which you can then transport via sneaker-net to the air-gaped machine. A subsequent `git bundle unbundle ...` or `git fetch ...` allows you to ingest the new commits into the repository.

  (I always use `git bundle unbundle ...` because I had some problems with `git fetch` not working as expected. However, `git bundle unbundle` won't update any references for you, you'll need to fix up your branches manually if you use this variant. It's really a plumbing type command, as the man-page rightly notes.)

Comment: Good point, thank you. I have edited the question to explain that I will be able to git push/pull normally once the repos are set up. But I'm glad to know about git bundle, and your answer will also be helpful to others who find this question.

Comment: Hmmm, I wonder who found my answer so unhelpful that they would downvote it. And, most importantly, why?